# Fixed position div to overflow containing div

Tags: html, css

How can I get it so div `.inner` covers the entire screen? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TrevTheDev/f5U6v/3/)

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
   <div id="inner">This should cover the entire screen</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
     margin: auto;   width: 100%;
     top: 0; bottom: 0;
     height: 100vh;
     max-width: 20rem;
     background: blue;
}

.inner {
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    position: fixed;
    background: gray;
    z-index: 2
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `css`, it should be `#inner`

```
#inner {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: fixed;
    background: gray;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - silly typo on my part.  The actual issue I was having is that the .outer div had -webkit-perspective: 1000px set which prevented .outer from occupying the full screen.  Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Change the attribute of the inner `div` which is `id` to `class`

**HTML:**

```
<div class="outer">
   <div class="inner">This should cover the entire screen</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.outer {
     margin: auto;   width: 100%;
     top: 0; bottom: 0;
     height: 100vh;
     max-width: 20rem;
     background: blue;
}

.inner {
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    position: fixed;
    background: gray;
    z-index: 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `.inner` with `#inner` in your css file also don't need to give `right:0;` and `bottom:0;` in inner css

Answer (score 0):

Try setting width to min-width instead.

```
.outer {
     margin: auto;
     min-width: 100%;
     top: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     height: 100vh;
     max-width: 20rem;
     background: blue;
}
```